# How to resolve null pointer exception in selenium when page factory method is used

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 classes - one for page locator, one for page action and the other one as script to execute the function. am getting nullpointer exception in main scripts where the function is called. Can anyone help me out, please!!!!.

The following are the code :

1. HomePageLocator.page

public class HomePageLocator{
       WebDriver driver;
    public HomePageLocator(WebDriver driver)
       {
            this.driver= driver;
        }

```
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div/div/nav/div[1]/a")
    public WebElement signIn;
```

}

2. HomePageAction.page
   public class HomePageAction{

   public WebDriver driver;
   public HomePageLocator homepageor;

   public HomePageAction() {

   ```
   this.homepage = new HomePageLocator(driver);
   PageFactory.initElements(driver, this.homepage);
   ```

   }

   public  void login()  {
       homepageor.signIn.click();
       }
3. BaseTestCase.java

public class BaseTestCase {

```
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable  {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\Executables\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Home page validation
    HomePageAction homepageaction= new HomePageAction();
    homepageaction.login();


}
```

Note : Am getting exception in line (homepageaction.login();)
the following is the exception logs :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.click(Unknown Source)
    at com.way2.Pages.actions.HomePage.login(HomePageAction.java:31)
    at com.way2.Testcases.BaseTestCase.main(BaseTestCase.java:35)

Comment: Could you please properly format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating  the driver in main class, but not passing it to homepageAction
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable  {

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\Executables\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Try to pass driver as 
HomePageAction homepageaction= new HomePageAction(driver);
this.driver =driver